# Booting into text mode - how can I fix it?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, text-mode

I upgrade my Ubuntu to 11.10. I restarted and it worked perfectly until now when I restarted again and it is now in text mode after I login. Can somebody please provided some suggestions on what I should do? I do not understand what happened.

- I tried restarting lightdm but it is already running.

Answer (score 1):

You could try restarting the graphical side by logging in in text mode and then typing the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

If that command gives errors, please add them to your question (using the edit link).

Comment: I tried what you suggest but it's doing nothing. It's showing me the following thing: start:Job is already running:lightdm

Comment: Try hitting Ctrl+Alt+7 when you encounter the text-based login and see if the graphical login shows up.

Comment: @nitstorm: You mean `Ctrl+Alt+F7`.

Comment: It's doing nothing

Comment: I tried Ctrl+Alt+F7 but it's doing nothing

Comment: It appears the graphical screen where to type my password but after that a terminal is opening

Comment: What video card you have? And what videodriver is installed?

Answer (score 1):

I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then returning to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, very inconvenient and I don't know what caused it, but it works.