# LUbuntu starts only in text mode

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, xorg, lxde

After some changes (I do not remember what I change) my system (lubuntu) does not automatically boot in graphical mode. After system start I have to log in (in text mode) and after that type "sudo startx" command graphical interface starts.

I would be grateful if somebody could help me deal with that problem.

Best regards, 
patlas

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67599/booting-into-text-mode-how-can-i-fix-it?rq=1

Comment: I have seen that solution but it doesn't help me to deal with it.

Comment: @PatLas: exactly what doesn't work in above solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open gedit and paste the following (ignore "):

> "#!/bin/sh -e
>
> sudo startx
>
> exit 0"

2. Save it as anyname.sh (in this example I have saved this file in "dir" folder which is present in your home directory). You might need to change the permissions to this file. To do so type:

`chmod a+x /home/username/dir/anyname.sh`

3. Then type:

   `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
4. Add the following above the line "exit 0":

   `sudo sh /home/username/dir/anyname.sh`
5. Restart and see if it works.

Comment: Thaks, I try to figure out what I've done wrong for almost all night but your answer helps me in few seconds.

Comment: Glad I could help you!